# Remove a parts of string and put it inside Array

Tags: java

I want to remove a parts of string.

for example:

Original string:

```
1     |  2  | 3
[A]B  |  C  | [D]
C[D]  |  C
```

I want only the parts which not contained within `[]`

Future result:

```
1 2 3 B C
```

Comment: What code have you tried/what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)!

```
    String input = "1 | 2 | 3 | [A] | B | C | [D] | C | [D] | C";
    System.out.println("initial input: " + input);
    input = input.replaceAll(" +\\[.*?\\] +\\|?",""); // remove [..] from the string
    System.out.println("filtered: " + input);
    String[] arr = input.split(" \\| "); // split the remaining parts into an array
    System.out.println("arr: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
initial input: 1 | 2 | 3 | [A] | B | C | [D] | C | [D] | C                                                                                             
filtered: 1 | 2 | 3 | B | C | C | C                                                                                                                    
arr: [1, 2, 3, B, C, C, C]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using java `stream`, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1 | 2 | 3 | [A]B | C | [D] | C[D] | C ";
    String filter = "\\[.*\\]";
    Arrays.stream(input.split("\\|"))
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll(filter, ""))
        .filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty())
        .map(s -> s.trim())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The above method splits the string with '|', removes substring contained in `[]` and prints the remaining tokens if they are not empty.

If you want unique elements only, then you can replace `.forEach(System.out::println)` with `.collect(Collectors.toSet())`, that will return a set with unique elements.